# How to change the color of the placeholder in material UI React js

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

How do I change the color of the background and the flashing color of the Skeleton component in Material UI ?

I'm trying to set custom styling for them as shown below:

```
<Skeleton variant="circle" classes={{root:'placeholder-animation'}} animation="wave" width={56} height={56} />
```

```
.placeholder-animation{
    background: chartreuse;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material-ui use `makeStyles` to override styles with global class names.

Reading the [Material-ui doc](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes), it seems that tou have more than one way to go.

You could use `makeStyles` to override styles with global class names.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: red,
  }
});

... 

<Skeleton variant="circle" classes={{root: classes.root}} animation="wave" width={56} height={56} />
```

Or you could simply use `className`

```
<Skeleton variant="circle" className="placeholder-animation" animation="wave" width={56} height={56} />
```

```
.placeholder-animation{
    background: chartreuse;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sx={{"&::after":{background: `linear-gradient( 90deg, transparent, #B4AFA5, transparent)`}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any class to change color of placeholder you can use sudo selector to change color of placeholder check this

```
::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: red;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: red;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: red;
}
```

here is working example

```css
::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: red;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Write somthing.">
```

Comment: I'll try it out !!